# Is it possible to make the Breadth First Search Algorithm recursive?

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, recursive-algorithms

I'm a student an I see the BFS Algorithm for graph exploration. I see the DFS algorithm too and this one is easily thinkable in a recursive mode.
But is it possible for the BFS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always rewrite any iterative algorithm to a tail-recursive one -- in this case, by passing the entire work list as a parameter to a recursive call instead of jumping back to the top of the loop.

However, I don't think doing so would be particularly enlightening for breadth-first, except if you have to implement it in a language that has recursion but no explicit iteration constructs.